# Playwright API post request failed

Tags: playwright, playwright-typescript

I have a code where I pick the final url after creating a reservation, then I cut the ID of reservation and I want to put it into post link.

I have something like this:

```
        let reservationURL = page.url()
        let slicedURL = reservationURL.split('/')
        console.log(slicedURL[slicedURL.length - 3])
        let reservation_id = slicedURL[slicedURL.length - 3]

        const response = await request.post('https:mywebapi/{reservation_id)}/cancel', {
            data: {
                reservation_id: { reservation_id },
            },
        })
        expect(response.status()).toBe(200)
```

I have 404 response status not 200.

Comment: `https:mywebapi` looks invalid. Shouldn't that be `https://mywebapi`? Please share a [mcve] otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: Please share the complete code of the test script.

Comment: @Rafal Zajac, And your config file code as well.